# Parse txBytes,rxBytes,rxPackets,txPackets from /proc/net/dev using c

Tags: c

I tried to Parse txBytes,rxBytes,rxPackets,txPackets from /proc/net/dev using c. Output is not as i expected. Here is the core of my code

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file) != NULL) {
conv = sscanf( buf, "%[^:]: %Lu %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %Lu %*u %*u %*u     %*u %*u %*u %*u", ifname, &rxBytes, &txBytes );
    printf("%s %Lu %Lu\n",ifname,rxBytes,txBytes);
    conv = 0;
    ifacesCount++;
 }
```

Here the file is /proc/net/dev and buf size is 500. I want to extract the interface name,txBytes,rxBytes,rxPackets,txPackets

Comment: Where is the parsing logic can you please share, along with what are you expecting. Please be more verbose, help community to understand how can they help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please re-frame your question, tell us what you tried, how, and what happened, what you think is wrong and how we can help.

Comment: Without the size of buf, and how you've allocated buf, this cannot be solved.

Comment: hey man, I said allocated 500 bytes of memory using malloc.

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code sample, I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/net/dev", "r");
    char buf[200], ifname[20];
    unsigned long int r_bytes, t_bytes, r_packets, t_packets;

    // skip first two lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fgets(buf, 200, fp);
    }

    while (fgets(buf, 200, fp)) {
        sscanf(buf, "%[^:]: %lu %lu %*lu %*lu %*lu %*lu %*lu %*lu %lu %lu",
               ifname, &r_bytes, &r_packets, &t_bytes, &t_packets);
        printf("%s: rbytes: %lu rpackets: %lu tbytes: %lu tpackets: %lu\n",
               ifname, r_bytes, r_packets, t_bytes, t_packets);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

> lo: rbytes: 22975300 rpackets: 459506 tbytes: 22975300 tpackets: 459506
>   wlp2s0: rbytes: 2419131107 rpackets: 1820658 tbytes: 109438292 tpackets: 877583
>   eno1: rbytes: 15984078 rpackets: 55391 tbytes: 3078636 tpackets: 13019

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: I wanted to skip first two lines. I missed it